# How to query for 2 different images?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'd like to query for 2 images, `images/me.jpg` and `images/boxing.png`.

Not sure how I would do it in graphql:

```
query AboutQuery {
    file(relativePath: { eq: ("images/me.jpg"|"images.boxing.png") }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
query AboutQuery {
    file(relativePath: { regex: "images" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see in [GraphQL Query Reference](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#filter) you can use a regular expression to match your `relativePath`, in your case your need to match `"images"`.

Optionally you can also use `in` filter (that accepts multiple values in the array) to match `["images"]`:

```
query AboutQuery {
    file(relativePath: { in: ["images"] }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Being a single value, the regular expression is the best approach.